# Как удалить значение из массива

Tags: javascript, массивы

Дано: в массиве имеется `user object`. Каждый `user` имеет `name` и `password`. У кого в имени найдется буква **"r"** удалить из данного массива и перенести в другой массив. Маленький пример

```
var a = [{
    name: "Rixter",
    password: "ksakkd12ks"
}, {
    name: "Rudolf",
    password: "asfsa2sfaa"
}, {
    name: "Masha",
    password: asfefds12
}]
```

Нужно удалить из данного массива пользователя `Rixter` и `Rudolf` и перенести в другой пустой массив

Answer (score 4):

Воспользуйтесь методом [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
var a = [
{name: "Rixter",
password: "ksakkd12ks"},
{name: "Rudolf",
password: "asfsa2sfaa"
},
{name: "Masha",
password: "asfefds12"},
];

var another_array = a.filter(user => user.name.toLowerCase().includes('r'));
var a = a.filter(user => !user.name.toLowerCase().includes('r'));

console.log(a, another_array);
```

Splice:

```js
var a = [
    {name: "Rixter",
    password: "ksakkd12ks"},
    {name: "Rudolf",
    password: "asfsa2sfaa"
    },
    {name: "Masha",
    password: "asfefds12"},
];

var r_index, r_array = [];

while(-1 != (r_index = a.findIndex(user => user.name.toLowerCase().includes('r'))))
r_array.push(a.splice(r_index,1)[0]);

console.log(a, '\n\n', r_array);
```

Comment: А просто с помощью cplice?

Comment: @КаренОганнисян Можно и splice, только в таком случае вам придется сначала найти индексы нужных элементов

Comment: Можно пример? Пожалуйста

Comment: @КаренОганнисян Привел пример. можно было сделать почитаемее, конечно, но в любом случае код будет более запутанный, чем с filter

Answer (score 2):

Если порядок следования пользователей в новом массиве не имеет значения и нужно реализовать именно через splice, то вот ещё один вариант:

```js
let a = [
    {name: "Rixter", password: "ksakkd12ks"},
    {name: "Rudolf", password: "asfsa2sfaa"},
    {name: "Masha", password: "asfefds12"}
];
let b = [];
for (let i = a.length - 1, r = /r/i; i >= 0; i--) {
    r.test(a[i].name) && (b = b.concat(a.splice(i, 1)));
}
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
```

Если порядок важен, то надо только поменять вставку их в массиве - в начало, а не в конец.

Comment: зачем использовать `concat`  и присваивание если можно `unshift` или  `push`?

Comment: лаконично. можно и пушить, но тогда надо не забыть вынуть первый элемент результата сплайса. сути не меняет.

Answer (score 1):

Модификация ответа @Darth с единственным вызовом `filter()`:

```js
var a = [{
    name: "Rixter",
    password: "ksakkd12ks"
  },
  {
    name: "Rudolf",
    password: "asfsa2sfaa"
  },
  {
    name: "Masha",
    password: "asfefds12"
  },
];

let another_array = [];
a = a.filter(user => {
  if (user.name.toLowerCase().includes('r')) {
    another_array.push(user);
    return false;
  }
  return true;
});
console.log(a, another_array);
```